# Can I avoid so many if statements?

Tags: java

In my project, the choice in one ComboBox affects the options available in the next ComboBox... I'm pretty new at this but if I'm right, I'm seeing every String here as an if/else statement inside the actionListener.  Is there any way to whittle this down or is it just time to crack my knuckles and get typing (If you see 2 models with the same exact strings, that's only because all the individual strings haven't been added yet)?

```
//Model Dropdown
final DefaultComboBoxModel termModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Hypercom", "DejaVoo", "Nurit", "Verifone"});

//Default Dropdown
final DefaultComboBoxModel slctAbove = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"Select Option Above"});


//Terminal Dropdowns
final DefaultComboBoxModel hSpecModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "T7Plus", "4205", "4210", "4220", "4230"});
final DefaultComboBoxModel dSpecModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Dial", "IP", "Wireless"});
final DefaultComboBoxModel nSpecModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "2085", "3020", "8320 Dial", "8320 IP", "8400 Dial", "8400 IP"});
final DefaultComboBoxModel vSpecModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Global Dial", "Global IP", "TPS Dial", "TPS IP", "Ptech Dial", "Ptech IP"});

//Call Type Dropdown
final DefaultComboBoxModel callReason = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Download", "Troubleshoot"});

//Error Dropdowns
//Hypercom
final DefaultComboBoxModel hypError = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Invalid Merch ID", "Printer Error", "Retry Batch Trans", "AP Dupe", "Invalid Balance Settlement"});

//DejaVoo
final DefaultComboBoxModel dejaError = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Invalid Merch ID", "Invalid Batch #", "AP Dupe"});
final DefaultComboBoxModel dejaMError = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Invalid Merch ID", "Invalid Batch #", "Transport Layer Abort", "AP Dupe"});

//Nurit
final DefaultComboBoxModel nuritDError = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Invalid Merch ID", "Invalid DUKPT Key", "Invalid Balance Settlement", "AP Dupe", "Secure Capture", "Invalid Term ID", "Open Tab", "No Host Response"});
final DefaultComboBoxModel nuritIpError = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Invalid Merch ID", "Invalid DUKPT Key", "Invalid Balance Settlement", "AP Dupe", "Secure Capture", "Invalid Term ID", "Open Tab", "No Host Response"});
final DefaultComboBoxModel nuritWError = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Invalid Merch ID", "Invalid DUKPT Key", "Invalid Balance Settlement", "AP Dupe", "Secure Capture", "Invalid Term ID", "Open Tab", "No Host Response", "Rad Fail", "No Net"});

//Verifone
final DefaultComboBoxModel verifError = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
        "Choose One...", "Invalid Merch ID", "Invalid DUKPT Key", "Invalid Balance Settlement", "AP Dupe", "Keyboard Locked", "Invalid Term ID", "Card Not Supported", "Comm Error"});
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing data with code which can lead to a very inflexible program. Better to hold that data in some file, either a database or XML file, and then use it to populate your combo boxes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's actually a really interesting idea and I'm kind of excited about giving that a shot. Time to get reading.  Thanks again (You're all over this place tonight, lol)

Comment: Every time you want to avoid if statements in a OO programming language consider some schematics before coding and study some design patterns http://www.oodesign.com/